# Continuity on endpoints

Tags: real-analysis

I am attempting to solve a proof using mean value theorem, however, all we were given is that $f$ is differentiable at $c\in (a,b)$. I know that this means $f$ is continuous at all $c\in (a,b)$ but how do I prove that it is also continuous on $[a,b]$ without knowing if $f$ is uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary. If $f(x)=1/x$ for $x\in(0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$, then $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ but it is not continuous at $x=0$.

Consider another function $g(x)=\sin(1/x)$ for $x\in(0,1]$ and $g(0)=0$, once again it has such the properties.